# CGPoint: Determining & scrolling to bottom edge of UIView on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, cgpoint

I'm trying to make an app load already scrolled to the bottom of a `UIView` that I've got setup.

I did some research and found the `setContentOffset:animated:` method to get the point that I want. But as anybody who's also familiar with that method will know, the content offset asks for a `CGPoint`. I'm not exactly sure how to retrieve the bottom of a `UIView` with a `CGPoint`.

I've tried looking for somebody else who has asked how to do what I'm trying to do, and to my amazement, I didn't actually find anyone who had asked how to detect the bottom of a `UIView`, and then set the content offset to that point.

I would post some sample code, but I wouldn't even know where to start.

Could anybody help move me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: The coordinates of the bottom most point of the scroll view would be CGPointMake(sv.contentSize.width,sv.contentSize.height)]

Comment: The view I'm trying to scroll to the bottom of isn't the entire view. It's like 200 pixels down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this for scrolling the UIScrollView to the bottom of the View

```
CGPoint bottom = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);
[scrollView setContentOffset:bottom animated:YES];
```

Comment: The view I'm trying to scroll to the bottom of isn't the entire view. It's like 200 pixels down.

Comment: Even though it is 200px this code works. You are telling that scrollView height is 200px?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I am or not. I'm just continually guessing. Which value should be the `UIView`? And which one should be the `UIScrollView`? I haven't gotten the app default scroll to anything yet either.

Comment: You should read the documentation. UIView has no functionality of scrolling. Only scrollview has the capability of scrolling. Scroll View has content size which can be more than the UIWindow size. so you can set the content offset of the scroll view. For details check the documentation of the [scrollview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Comment: I'm aware that `UIView` doesn't scroll. That wouldn't make any sense. All I'm saying is that I want the view to load with the top set to the bottom of edge of a `UIView` that's approximately 200px down the window's total frame. Everything is subclassed within a `UIScrollView`, and I've set the delegates properly. I've tried this before and I couldn't even get the code to do anything... period.

Comment: Although, I will take another look at documentation.

Comment: Alright, I figured out I was just calling the method too soon and it was getting reset while in viewDidLoad.